# Search for word repeated many times in line by shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have file containing word of "TEMPO" repeated many times in every line.
as in example:

```
(TAF HECA 312300Z 0100/0206 32008KT 6000 NSC TEMPO 0100/0107 VRB03KT 4000HZ PROB40 TEMPO 0101/0106 2000BR BECMG 0109/0111 35010KT 9999 SCT025=)
```

I want to search for (TEMPO) one by one to make if condition:

if the hour after 1st (TEMPO) >= 1st 6 hour stop and if not complete reading and search for 2nd (TEMPO).My script is:

```
   #!/bin/sh
      cat taf2 | while read line 
    do
    ihour1=`echo $line |cut -d "Z" -f2 | awk '{ print substr($0,2,4) }'`
    lhour1=`echo $line |cut -d "Z" -f2 | awk '{ print substr($0,7,4) }'`
    l6hour1=`expr $ihour1 + 6`
    printf -v l6hour1 "%04d" $l6hour1 ; echo $l6hour1
    line2=`echo $line | sed "s:Z ${ihour1}/${lhour1}:Z      ${ihour1}/${l6hour1}:g"`
    #echo $line2
    # search for TEMPO
    ihour2=`echo $line2 |awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO")  {val[++c]=substr($(I+1),1,4);{print $(I+1)};}}'|awk '{print substr($0,1,4)}'`
    lhour2=`echo $line2 |awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO") {print  $(I+1)};}'|awk '{print substr($0,6,4)}'`
    ##
    count_tempo=`echo $ihour2 |wc -w`
    for cc in {1..$count_tempo};do
    echo $ihour2 $val[$cc] 
    if [ $ihour2 -ge $l6hour1 ]; then
    fline=`echo $line2 | sed "s: TEMPO.*::g"`
    echo no
    else
    fline=`echo $line2| sed "s:TEMPO ${ihour2}/${lhour2}:TEMPO  ${ihour2}/${l6hour1}:g"`
    echo yes
    fi
    echo $fline "=" >>ttt
    done
    done
    ####
```

I want to make a loop over number of TEMPO, read the 1st alone, and then may go to the next or not. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: _if - - equal certain value stop_ stop the program execution completely or just proceed to the next line? No need to print anything? Please post expected output if any.

Comment: Do you want your tempo condition to continue even on the second line of file or each line must be treated as a seperate /unique case?

Comment: I want the condition to be for each separate line

Answer (score 0):

> First, try this to print all the Hour Values corresponding to TEMPO -

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO") {print substr($(I+1),1,4)}}' f
```

> And if you want to stop after searching particular Hour value after TEMPO,
>   check below input file and solution -

```
 cat f ###added one more TEMPO with 0110/0111 in last

 TAF HECA 312300Z 0100/0206 32008KT 6000 NSC TEMPO 0100/0107 VRB03KT 4000HZ PROB40 TEMPO 0101/0106 2000BR BECMG 0109/0111 08KT 6000 NSC TEMPO 0110/0111
```

> Currently, we have three TEMPO value -

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO") {a[$(I+1)]++}} END {for(i in a) print substr(i,1,4)}' f
0110
0101
0100
```

> Now if I want to stop after searching 0101 then I will use below
>   command -

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO") {a[$(I+1)]++}} END {for(i in a) if(substr(i,1,4) != "0101") {print substr(i,1,4)} else {print substr(i,1,4);exit}}' f
0110
0101
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk (regex `FS`):

```
$ awk -F"[ /]" -v certain_value="0100" '            # set FS to " " or "/"
/TEMPO/{                                            # all records with TEMPO 
    for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++)                          # iterate all but last field
        if($i=="TEMPO" && $(i+1)==certain_value) {  # if match
            print $(i+1)                            # output certain_value
            next                                    # move to process next record
        }
}'  file
0100
```

If `TEMPO` is on every record you can remove from the code the lines:

```
/TEMPO/ {
}          # basically either will do
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe (read: definitely!) you should add all these comments to your question for a lots of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not reproducable in my Debian (GNU Awk 4.1.4)
Moreover, you don't have to pipe awk to another awk - You can apply substr directly in the same awk.

```
$ a="(TAF HECA 312300Z 0100/0206 32008KT 6000 NSC TEMPO 0100/0107 VRB03KT 4000HZ PROB40 TEMPO 0101/0106 2000BR BECMG 0109/0111 35010KT 9999 SCT025=)"
$ awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "TEMPO") {val[++c]=substr($(I+1),1,4);print val[c]}}' <<<"$a"
0100
0101
```

In above test, i store values of TEMPO in an array `val`.
`val[1]` will have the first found TEMPO value, `val[2]` will keep second found tempo value, etc.

You can then loop through this array (i.e length(val) returns length (number of elements) of array val) and you can built your own condition checks.

Comment: I tried to make that, but when I tried to make a loop, I think I write it in wrong way. when I execute the script in the question, the error is:  line 17: [: too many arguments
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command